# Missing nameservers reported by parent

Tags: nameserver, dns-hosting

The following error came while i checked my dns configurations.But i havent mentioned this name servers in the doamin nameserver

```
FAIL: The following nameservers are listed at your nameservers as nameservers for your domain, but are not listed at the parent nameservers (see RFC2181 5.4.1). You need to make sure that these nameservers are working.If they are not working ok, you may have problems! 

ns1.nowheredesigns.com
ns2.nowheredesigns.com
```

Comment: Maybe you could give us the actual domain name so that we can give you intelligent, informed answers.

Comment: http://www.intodns.com/globaltechtrain.com

Comment: @joeqwerty i have provided the link from where i got the error.Does this make sense.

Comment: You have no idea who `clee-designs.com` is?  They didn't design your web site or anything?  They seem to have listed an email address of `clee.creativedesigns@gmail.com`.  If they aren't supposed to be providing your DNS, which servers should it be hosted on?

Comment: @Zoredache its my cient ,bvut they want to change that name server to ns1.livehostsupport.com .  but i dont see ns1clee-designs.com in the domain or hosting control panel they provided.domain is from godaddy where i chnaged the nameserver.the hosting has a cpanel, but couldnt find this there

Answer (score 1):

Use this DNS delegation tool to verify what the Internet gets of your zone:

http://www.buddyns.com/delegation-lab/globaltechtrain.com

It tells you what nameservers your clients receive for your zone at every delegation step, and it shows graphically which entries are inconsistent between the registry and your zone.

Answer (score 0):

`ns1.clee-designs.com` and `ns2.clee-designs.com` are listed as NS records for the `globaltechtrain.com.` DNS zone hosted on your livehostsupport.com.

As it stands, you are likely getting some intermittent slow DNS resolution to the site.

You should definitely remove them.